# Countries with a Census

Tags: metadata, census, global

I am looking for a list of countries that have a census. The attributes would be the last census dates or dates of censuses and the census unit. I do not want variables from a census but meta information such as:

1. Has a census:Yes / No
2. Date(s) of census: 1992, 2002, decadal, etc.
3. Census geographies: Blocks / enumeration districts.

Was hopeful something may exist at UN / World Bank / IMF level or compiled by an academic.

A census of censuses.

This is the best I have come up with so far (useful but just a start): [Census in Different Countries of the World (dec 2010)](http://odisha.gov.in/e-magazine/Orissareview/2010/December/engpdf/26-36.pdf) and [UN 2010 World Population and Housing Census Programme](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/demographic/sources/census/2010_PHC/default.htm). I am also working my way through [IPUMS](https://international.ipums.org/international/).

If you just know for a large group of countries this will help. Such as the information for all of Africa then this would help. I am trying to avoid going country-by-country for 200 countries.

Answer (score 4):

Most countries of the world have a Department of Statistics where they compile Census data. The various world census datasets, like CIA WFB, UN statistics, and Worldbank get their information from these countries.

CIA WFB: https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2119.html

UNSTATS: http://unstats.un.org/unsd/demographic/products/vitstats/

WorldBank: http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL

The link below is a crowd sourced catalog on government portals. Click on the option 'Census/Demographics'. This will give you links to the countries' specific census data.

http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/

Comment: Thanks Andrew but I specifically do not want census data. See the line, "I do not want variables from a census." Census data is easy to obtain. What I want are authoritative sources on when censuses occur, what is the unit of the census, and such for all countries. I am aware of all those links to census data and some far better ones. I am looking for global meta-census information.